# How can I apply a blur to vertex group weights using python?

Tags: python, weight-painting

It's a long story, but I need to use "Assign Weights" to a mesh in order to get it to export properly into another program.  But the assignment (from the particular rig needed) results in very blocky weighting.  When I use the Blur tool it works great, and the weights are perfect, but I have to do this a few hundred times, on a few dozen bones per mesh, so I was looking for a way to automate it.

I found a couple of scripts that propose to do this, but in the first case it's not a Python script ( https://github.com/assumptionsoup/Blur-Weights ) and I don't know how to run or install Javascript stuff into Blender and in the second case it won't install for me (it runs, but doesn't seem to do anything.

http://linetestjournals.blogspot.com/2010/12/smooth-vertex-group-weights-in-python.html

and the code:

http://pasteall.org/17726/python

The second case seems to contain the code I need, if I strip out all the other stuff that isn't smoothing, but I have zero idea how to get it to run over all vertex groups on the selected mesh.  Does anyone have some help on a stub calling open for the function to do that?  I would be eternally grateful.

Ah, okay, some more info -- I went ahead and finally did get the first script to install (silly me, I wasn't looking in the right place).  It runs, and gives me an error "Outdated internal index table - run ensure_lookup_table() first.

I assume that's a new function that must be called but I'm not sure what parameters to pass to get over this error.  So that's another possibility (and possibly an easier solution than trying to cannibalize the second python script).

Here's all that code:

```
''' Blurs all weights in the selected vertex group.

This is still one of my first blender addons, so please keep in mind I may be
implementing various operations badly or just plain wrong.'''

'''
*******************************************************************************
    License and Copyright
    Copyright 2012 Jordan Hueckstaedt
    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
'''

bl_info = {
    'name': 'Blur Weights',
    'author': 'Jordan Hueckstaedt',
    'version': (1, 0),
    'blender': (2, 63, 0),
    'location': 'View > Weight Tools > Blur',
    'warning': '', # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    'description': 'Blurs the weights in the selected vertex group.',
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "support": 'TESTING',
    'category': 'Paint'
}

import bpy
import bmesh
import math
# from mathutils import *

class BlurSettingsCollection(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    iterations = bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "Iter", 
        description = "Iterate this many times",
        default = 1,
        min = 1,
        soft_max = 20)

    factor = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name = "Factor", 
        description = "Laplace Factor",
        default = 0.5,
        soft_min = 0.0,
        soft_max = 1.0)

    operation = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Blur Operation",
        items = (('GAUSSIAN', "Gaussian", "Gaussian Blur"),
                ('AVERAGE', "Average", "Simple Average Blur"),
                ),
        )

    blur_type = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Blur Type",
        items = (('0', "Normal", "Normal Blur"),
                ('1', "Shrink", "Blur will only decrease values"),
                ('2', "Grow", "Blur will only increase values"),
                ),
        )

    selected_only = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = "Selected Only",
        default = False)



class BlurWeights( object ):
    def __init__(self, active_index = None):

        obj = bpy.context.active_object
        if active_index is None:
            active_index = obj.vertex_groups.active_index

        # Get a BMesh representation to access connectivity information
        bm_obj = bmesh.new()
        bm_obj.from_mesh(obj.data)

        # Find face masking.  Faces can only be found in bmesh, however,
        # in paint mode vert selection is not updated correctly to edit mode
        # or in bmesh, so vert selection can only be found through object.data
        # I suspect this is a bug.
        face_mask = obj.data.use_paint_mask
        vertex_mask = obj.data.use_paint_mask_vertex
        if face_mask:
            masked_face_verts = set([v.index for f in bm_obj.faces if f.select for v in f.verts])

        weights = [1.0 for x in range(len(obj.data.vertices))]
        vert_indexes = []
        vert_indexes_test = []
        vert_group_indexes = []
        connected_verts = []
        gaussian_weights = []

        # Convenience function to find group index
        def vert_group_index(vert, group_id):
            for x, group_info in enumerate(vert.groups):
                if group_info.group == group_id:
                    return x
            return None

        # Get weight info.  It's weird, I know
        for vert in obj.data.vertices:
            i = vert_group_index(vert, active_index)
            if i is not None:
                weights[vert.index] = vert.groups[i].weight

                # Skip if vert is not in mask.
                if not vert.hide and (not vertex_mask or vert.select) and (not face_mask or vert.index in masked_face_verts):
                    # Get group info
                    vert_indexes.append(vert.index)
                    vert_group_indexes.append(i)
                else:
                    vert_indexes_test.append(vert.index)

        # Sets are MUCH faster to test in than lists.  This made __init__ run 3x faster for me.
        vert_indexes_test = set(vert_indexes + vert_indexes_test)

        # Only use connected verts in which are in the group.  God this part was a bitch to get working.
        # Also, pre-calculate the guassian weights
        for x in reversed(range(len(vert_indexes))):
            vert = bm_obj.verts[vert_indexes[x]]

            connected_vert = [v.index for edge in vert.link_edges for v in edge.verts if v.index != vert.index and v.index in vert_indexes_test]            

            inclusive_verts = connected_vert + [vert.index]
            link_edges = [edge for edge in vert.link_edges if edge.verts[0].index in inclusive_verts and edge.verts[1].index in inclusive_verts]
            if not link_edges:
                # Orphaned vert
                vert_indexes.pop(x)
                vert_group_indexes.pop(x)
            else:
                connected_verts.append(connected_vert)

                # Pre-Calculate gaussian weights.
                avg_edge = sum([edge.calc_length() for edge in link_edges]) / len(link_edges)

                gaussian_weight = {'total_weight' : 0.0}
                for i in connected_vert:
                    distance = (vert.co - bm_obj.verts[i].co).length_squared
                    gaussian_weight[str(i)] = (1.0 /(avg_edge * math.sqrt(2.0 * math.pi))) * math.exp(-(distance)/(2.0 * avg_edge ** 2))
                    gaussian_weight['total_weight'] += gaussian_weight[str(i)]

                gaussian_weights.append( gaussian_weight )

        # The last for loop was iterating in reverse to allow removing indexes while iterating.
        # So these lists are reversed
        gaussian_weights.reverse()
        connected_verts.reverse()

        self.weights = weights
        self.vert_indexes = vert_indexes
        self.vert_group_indexes = vert_group_indexes
        self.connected_verts = connected_verts
        self.gaussian_weights = gaussian_weights
        self.active_index = active_index
        bm_obj.free()


    def execute(self, iterations = 1, factor = 0.5, do_gaussian = True, blur_type = 0, selected_only = False):
        ''' Calculate the blurred weights.
        blur_type options:
        0 - Normal
        1 - Shrink
        2 - Grow
        '''

        # Whatever you do, never save obj to a class member variable.  Blender will freeze.
        obj = bpy.context.active_object

        # Make a copy of weights.  Otherwise edits will be compounded onto the initial weight set.
        weights = self.weights[:]

        for i in range(iterations):
            new_weights = weights
            for x, i in enumerate(self.vert_indexes):
                if not selected_only  or (not do_gaussian and obj.data.vertices[i].select):
                    # Skip guassian if the denominator in the weight function is 0 
                    # Which would most likely mean all the connected verts are in the same position
                    if do_gaussian and self.gaussian_weights[x]['total_weight'] > 0.0:
                        average_weight = 0
                        for v in self.connected_verts[x]:
                            average_weight += self.gaussian_weights[x][str(v)] / self.gaussian_weights[x]['total_weight'] * weights[v]
                    else:
                        # average_weight = sum([weights[v] for v in self.connected_verts[x]]) / len(self.connected_verts[x])
                        average_weight = 0
                        num_set = 0
                        for v in self.connected_verts[x]:
                            if not selected_only or obj.data.vertices[v].select:
                                average_weight += weights[v]
                                num_set += 1
                        if num_set:
                            average_weight /= num_set
                        else:
                            continue

                    # Assign new weights with using laplace factor (or can I just call this a lerp? hmmm...)
                    new_weights[i] = factor * average_weight + (1.0 - factor) * weights[i]

                    # Grow or shrink weights.
                    if blur_type == 1:
                        new_weights[i] = min(new_weights[i], self.weights[i])
                    elif blur_type == 2:
                        new_weights[i] = max(new_weights[i], self.weights[i])

            weights = new_weights[:]

        # Update object weights
        for x, i in enumerate(self.vert_indexes):
            obj.data.vertices[i].groups[self.vert_group_indexes[x]].weight = weights[i]
        obj.data.update()

class WeightPaintBlurAll(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.weightpaint_blur_all"
    bl_label = "Blur"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    settings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = BlurSettingsCollection)

    active_index = None
    blur = None

    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.prop(self.settings, "iterations", text = "Iter")
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.prop(self.settings, "selected_only")
        # self.layout.prop(self, "factor")
        box = self.layout.box()
        row = box.row()
        row.prop(self.settings, "operation", expand = True)
        box = self.layout.box()
        row = box.row()
        row.prop(self.settings, "blur_type", expand = True)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        return (obj and obj.mode == 'WEIGHT_PAINT' and obj.type == 'MESH' and len(obj.vertex_groups) > 0)

    def execute(self, context):
        # Lots of addons seem to disable undo during execution.  For whatever reason, 
        # I had difficulty with the undo queue reliably being turned back on, so I'm leaving this out.
        # global_undo_state = context.user_preferences.edit.use_global_undo
        # context.user_preferences.edit.use_global_undo = False

        do_gaussian = self.settings.operation == 'GAUSSIAN'

        # Initialize the blur operator if it hasn't been.
        if self.blur is None:
            self.blur = BlurWeights( self.active_index )

        self.blur.execute( iterations = self.settings.iterations, 
            factor = self.settings.factor, do_gaussian = do_gaussian,
            blur_type = int(self.settings.blur_type),
            selected_only = self.settings.selected_only)

        # This is a hack.  For some reason the active vertex group changes during execution,
        # Only when used from the Blur PANEL (not the regular blur buttons in the weight paint section)
        # And this seems to happen even when I touch NOTHING related to it (I tried commenting out the
        # blur operation and the active_index query in invoke).  I have...no clue.
        if self.active_index is not None:
            context.active_object.vertex_groups.active_index = self.active_index

        # context.user_preferences.edit.use_global_undo = global_undo_state
        return{'FINISHED'} 

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        for key, value in context.scene.weightpaint_blur_all_settings.items():
            self.settings[key] = value
        self.active_index = context.active_object.vertex_groups.active_index
        return self.execute(context)

def panel_func(self, context):  
    row = self.layout.row(align = True).split(0.35)
    row.alignment = 'EXPAND'
    row.operator("object.weightpaint_blur_all", text="Blur")
    scn = context.scene
    row.prop(scn.weightpaint_blur_all_settings, "iterations")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(BlurSettingsCollection)
    bpy.utils.register_class(WeightPaintBlurAll)
    bpy.types.Scene.weightpaint_blur_all_settings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = BlurSettingsCollection)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_tools_weightpaint.append(panel_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WeightPaintBlurAll)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_tools_weightpaint.remove(panel_func)

    del bpy.types.Scene.weightpaint_blur_all_settings
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlurSettingsCollection)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, nevermind, I found that someone had already posted a fix for this on Github (I'm still a bit unfamiliar with it and didn't look properly.  Sigh).

The fix is to add these particular lines:

```
if hasattr(bm_obj.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"):
            bm_obj.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
```

right before you assign the vert to one of the indexes.  Anyway, works fine now.

Comment: No, it actually doesn't -- while it "says" it's doing all vertex groups, it only does the active one, and for the life of me I can't figure the code out to make it work properly.  Perhaps I should ask this question again, more clearly.